# alpine apk: recursively list dependencies for package

Tags: dependency-management, alpine-linux, package-managers

I want to determine the dependency closure for a package, let's use npm as an example.  This includes packages that npm depends on, as well as their dependencies, recursively until we get to the leaves of this dependency tree.

I have tried `apk add --simulate npm`.  This lists any packages which apk would end up installing if apk did add nodejs, which is good. However, `apk add --simulate` will not list packages that area already installed.  My solution needs for stuff like `musl` and `alpine-baselayout` to be included as dependencies.

I have also tried `apk dot npm`.  This lists all packages and dependencies down to the root.  However, some dependencies have multiple providers, and `apk dot` includes both.  For example, `apk dot npm` includes edges for both `nodejs` and `nodejs-current` even though `apk add` would only install one of them.  How can I know which provider `apk` would choose?

Is there a way to ask apk for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

```
apk add npm
apk dot npm --installed
```

Works for me on apk-tools 2.14.0, compiled for x86_64.

```
Dot options:


 --errors              Consider only packages with errors
 --installed           Consider only installed packages
```